# Yammer Bearer token with SSO?

Tags: yammer

I have a brand new small JavaScript app running on "somedomain.sharepoint.com". We have enabled SSO with Yammer. So, when the user visits "yammer.com/somedomain" the network is immediately available. So far, so good :)

Now, when the user logs into SharePoint, my JavaScript app can request data from the Yammer REST API. The app is able to do all GET calls, including to the users own https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/current.json. However, POSTS are denied, because I need to send the bearer token along.

Question: Even when SSO is enabled, do I need to send all my users, through these horrible OAuth windows? Or is there another way to fetch this?

(When I use the yammer "embed" feed, with sso enabled. All calls in the embed contain the bearer token automatically, without any user actions.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to send users through the OAuth dialog from client-side code. It's a security prompt that users who've got Facebook, Twitter, Google+ or other social media accounts have seen in some form. It's designed to protect from specific classes of security issues.

It's best to combine some server-side code with client side code. Use the server-side flow and then securely store the resulting OAuth token. You can then have the OAuth token available and can reduce the number of times you need to send the user back to get another token.